# How to tokenize if there is different length between words

Tags: java, tokenize

So, I read and write back to it. Some of the spaces between strings in the file are of different length, and I was wondering how I could check to see if the length between words is different

I CAN ONLY USE substring and indexOf FOR THIS PROJECT

```
public class Tokenize
{     


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  {
    final String DELIMITER = " ";
    final String DELIMITER_TAB = "  ";
    int index = 0;

    BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(INPUT_FILE));
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(OUTPUT_FILE));
}
}
```

I want everything to be a separate line, like Special

Comment: I havent used the delimiter tab yet

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Does your white space really have semantic meaning?

Comment: its for a project, I have to sort text from a file

Comment: You should just use for(String token: lineOfText.split(DELIMITER+"+")) System.out.println(token);

Comment: I would probably use a `StringTokenizer`

Comment: I can't use those methods

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you know how to differentiate between the legth of spaces

Comment: What is the semantic meaning of the length of spaces? Why do you want to "count" the spaces, what does knowing the length of white space tell you? I ask (again) because most grammars want to treat any white space as semantically equivalent.

Comment: Because I want each string of characters to be on a separate line

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  did you look at the link to the file I posted

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two-dimensional list of integers, with one dimension holding three ints; each trio represents the length of the whitespace before the token, the start of the token, and the length of the token.  I would use substring to go through the string one character at a time, counting up either whitespace chars or token characters, and accumulating them to put in my counts/indices.  When you're done, you have a list of the tokens, and can easily see the spaces between them.  Only the first element can have a whitespace count of 0, in the case that your first token starts with the first character.

I don't see that you're going to need index, in this case.  You *could* use it, but I think it would make your code harder to read than just going through the string one character at a time.

Comment: can you give an outline of what that would look like

Comment: do you know how, what do you mean 2 dimensional list of integers

Comment: If you put "java two-dimensional array" into google, you get more examples than you can use.